# Parse strings within quotations

Tags: awk, sed

I have a log file that includes lines with the pattern as below. I want to extract the two strings within the quotations and write them to another file, each one in a separate column. (Not all lines have this pattern, but these specific lines come sequentially.)

## Input

```
(multiple lines of header)
Of these, 0 are new, while 1723332 are present in the base dataset.
Warning: Variants 'Variant47911' and 'Variant47910' have the same position. 
Warning: Variants 'exm2254099' and 'exm12471' have the same position.
Warning: Variants 'newrs140234726' and 'exm15862' have the same position.
```

## Desired output:

```
Variant47911     Variant47910
exm2254099       exm12471
newrs140234726   exm15862
```

This retrieves the lines but do not know how to specify the strings that need to be printed.

```
awk '/Warning: Variants '*'/ Input
```

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO for all Original poster of question, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the single quote as a field delimiter should get you most of the way there, and then you have to have a way to uniquely identify the lines you want to match. Below works for the sample you gave, but might have to be tweaked depending on the lines from the file that we're not seeing.

```
$ awk -v q="'" 'BEGIN {FS=q; OFS="\t"} /Warning: Variants/ && NF==5 {print $2, $4}' file
Variant47911    Variant47910
exm2254099      exm12471
newrs140234726  exm15862
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En "/Variant/{s/[^']*'([^']*)'[^']*/\1\t/g;T;s/.$//p}" file
```

For all lines that contain `Variant`, remove everything except the text between single quotes and tab separate the results.